# Getting com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes on JBoss EAP 7

Tags: jboss, jersey

My Environment: JBOSS EAP 7, Jersey Rest Service 1.15

Getting com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

web.xml

```
  <display-name>Rest App 2</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.app.service</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>


        <!-- <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> -->
    </servlet>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I tried all the different options, but no success.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried all the different options please elaborate

Comment: i mean: added  jboss_deployment_structure.xml  and applicationContext.xml files.

Comment: added lib folder in the war and created jboss module for all these libraries.  war file is showing all the class files with proper package structure, but i am not sure why it is throwing exception.  Do you need any more details on this?

Comment: Any suggestions or solution for this issue?

Comment: I suggest you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , then delete your question and re-ask it following that guide